# How to make a Point semi-transparent in a Visual Studio Point Chart?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts

How can I make a Point semi-transparent in a Visual Studio Point Chart?
I have many points close to each other, so I can't see if there are more than one at the same place. If they would be semi transparent multiple points at the same place should appear darker than a single point.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the color of the point using [`public static Color FromArgb( int alpha, int red, int green, int blue)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at1k42eh(v=vs.110).aspx) with a value of 128 to `alpha` to get a semi transparent point.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I do this?

Comment: He can set the Color of the whole Series or of single Points. Alpha may be quite a bit less that 128 and will still be nicely visible.